# How to play audio using this code in Grid View

Tags: android

I have been following this code on andriod developer site. This code displays pictures in a grid. What I want to do now is to play different sond each time user clicks on the image. How can I do that?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
int position, long id) {
//
Intent myIntent = null;
if(position==0){
//Play some sound...
//MediaPlayer sound= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alif);
// sound.start();

}
if(position==1){

Toast.makeText(Test.this, "" + "Baa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Want to play sound here
}
}

});
}
```

When I add this code: I get a compile error

> The method create(Context, int) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int)

```
if(position==0){
    MediaPlayer sound= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alif);
    sound.start();
}
```

Comment: What's not working about it? You have your MediaPlayer lines commented out (and poorly formatted for us to read). Do these lines cause a crash? Does nothing happen? Give us a better description of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
        button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    if ( mPlayer == null ) mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                    else mPlayer.stop();


                    try 
                    {
                        mPlayer.setVolume( (float)0.25 * n, (float)0.25 * n );
                        mPlayer.reset();

 // in here your sounds would be listed in an array - pick a random file each time.
                        mPlayer.setDataSource( strSoundFile );
                        mPlayer.prepare();
                        mPlayer.start();
                    } 
                    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) 
                    {

                        myViewUpdateHandler.sendMessage( msg );

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
                    {
                        myViewUpdateHandler.sendMessage( msg );

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) 
                    {
                        myViewUpdateHandler.sendMessage( msg );

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: if(position==0){
     MediaPlayer bismiallh2 = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alif);
        bismiallh.start();
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
final MediaPlayer sound= MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.alif);

Intent myIntent = null;
if(position==0){  sound.start();}
```